# SSD keeps disappearing after a shutdown

Tags: windows-10, ssd, samsung-ssd

I am having a strange problem, which started recently. I have an ASUS STRIX G G531GT Gaming Laptop, recently I have upgraded my second HDD from a Seagate SSHD to Samsung SSD 870 QVO.

Now my problem, the SSD keeps disappearing after booting from a shutdown. And it takes me a shutdown to bring it back to life. Even the BIOS stops detecting during its disappearing act.

My earlier Firecuda SSHD laptop was working fine without any problem.

When I reached out to Samsung support, they only have an option of replacing the SSD. I am wondering if there is any help here!

BTW, I use 
Windows 10 Pro Version  20H2
OS build 19042.985
Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.2020.0

Comment: I have a similar setup in my desktop computer and the second SSD drive is always alive (no difference between restart or shutdown).  Try updating your BIOS.

Comment: When does the SSD disappear? How do you know it disconnects?

I'd suggest editing your question to include more details surrounding the events. You can remove the details about Samsung support, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response @John, I have the latest BIOS the manufacturer has for this model!

Comment: @ndemarco, There is no specific event that causes SSD to disappear. After a shutdown and reboot post a few hours, the BIOS doesn't detect the SSD and I have to do 2-3 shutdown and restart iterations to get it back. I put the Samsung comment, as I see people refer to reaching the Manufacturer for support.